# How do I fix VirtualBox Bridged Adapter problem?

Tags: virtualbox

I have not had this problem in the past. 
I have searched the internet but not found a solution.
I have asked the same question in [Virtualbox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=96857) but not received any answers.

**I have the following setup**

- Host: Windows 10 (192.168.86.35), wired eth.
- VirtualBox v6.0.16
- Networking: Bridged Adapter
- Guest 1: Ubuntu 18.04 (192.168.86.29)
- Guest 2: Ubuntu 18.04 (192.168.86.26)

Both host and guests recieves IP from the same DHCP server and is on the same subnet.
Both host and guests can ping the DHCP server successfully or any WAN address for that matter.

**The problem:** However neither can ping each other.

Guest ping

```
avec@GUEST:~$ ping 192.168.86.35
PING 192.168.86.35 (192.168.86.35) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.86.35 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3050ms
```

Host ping

```
C:\>ping 192.168.86.29

Pinging 192.168.86.29 with 32 bytes of data:
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.

Ping statistics for 192.168.86.29:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

**What I have tried**

- Host: Turned Avast Shields off. There is no difference. I have not
  tried to uninstall Avast it as I do not think this is the problem.
- Guest: Condirmed Ubuntu firewall have "status: inactive"
- Host: Repaired later reinstalled Virtualbox
- Host: Started guest as Ubuntu Live cd. All is the same as running from the vdi (disk)
- Host: Created a second Guest (cloned Guest 1 vdi)

**Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be? I'm stuck.**

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and it had nothing to do with VirtualBox or the configuration/setup.

I had NordVPN installed and running as a background process on the host. 
There is a setting in NordVPN called "Invisibility on LAN" defaulting to ON. That was the problem. As fast as I turned that setting to OFF host and guests could reach each other.

**Turn 'invisibility on LAN' to OFF**
[image]

Comment: Also added the solution on [VirtualBox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=96857&p=470219#p470219).